# Color-coded timeline plot in R

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, timeline

I am working on visualising user touch interactions within a mobile application. I would like to plot them in a one-dimensional timeline that is color-coded by action type.

i.e., my two variables are time (in ms, on the x-axis) and type of touch (used to color-code the line). Colors should be able to be repeated.

Ideally the plot would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxt9F.png), and I have found [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251160/plot-timeline-in-r-as-single-labeled-bar-and-with-dates-at-the-x-axis-labels) which delivers something similar, but I'm wondering if there isn't something better.

Is there any other methods using R which will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the workings of a base R method. It's a bit hacky, but with some tweaking it should work nicely. I have removed the reliance on the `data.table`, `timeline`, and `ggplot` packages, opting for using the `polygon` function.

```
df <- data.frame(Set=c("x","y","z","x","y","z","x","y","z","x","y","z","x"),
       StartDate=c(1380708900,1402963200,1420070400,1421280000,1410912000,1396310400,1397520000,1418860800,1404172800,1405382400,1395100800,1412121600,1413331200),
       EndDate=  c(1395099900,1404171900,1421279100,1430985600,1412120700,1397519100,1402962300,1420069500,1405381500,1410911100,1396309500,1413330300,1418859900))

df$StartLabel <- as.POSIXct(df$StartDate,tz="UTC",origin="1970-01-01")
df$Set <- as.factor(df$Set)
```

Above sets up the `data.frame` object.

This sets up the plotting canvas

```
plot(c(df$StartDate[1], tail(df$EndDate,1)), c(0.4,0.65), 
     type='n', xlab='Time', ylab='', axes=FALSE)
```

This clunk-ily loops through your values and draws a colored polygon for each period of time for each observation

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  polygon(x=c(rep(df$StartDate[i],2), rep(df$EndDate[i],2)), 
          y=c(0.6,0.4,0.4,0.6), col=rainbow(3, alpha=0.75)[df$Set[i]],
          border=rainbow(3)[df$Set[i]])
}
```

Then I add in the axis (this could use some tweaking depending on how much of the date information you care to show.

```
axis(1, labels=df$StartLabel, at=df$StartDate)
```

Then this sets up the legend at the top of the plot.

```
legend('top', horiz=TRUE, 
       c('Test set', 'Training set', 'Validation set'), 
       pch=16, col=rainbow(3), bty='n', x.intersp=1.5, title='Group')
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: You can also use `rect` if you'd like to draw rectangles (slightly different input), but it doesn't really matter. `rect(df$StartDate[i], 0.4, df$endDate[i], 0.6)` would draw a rectangle in a similar way to using the general polygon function.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I was able to do exactly what I wanted using this very straightforward and well explained answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without a working example, I would suggest that you use `ggplot2` package (along with `ggfortify`), which allows you to map variables (here: action type) to color. A frequent alternative is size (of points/dots) or thickness (of lines).

In addition, you may find time-series `ts` objects (see [example/reference here](http://rpubs.com/sinhrks/plot_ts)) to be helpful. However, it is not a requirement for the type of data that you're interested in plotting. Best of luck!