# Timelime in r with ggplot without determining initial and final values

Tags: r, ggplot2, timeline

I need help in creating a script for a graph. The information is below:

I have this fictitious data

```
table <- data.frame(ind = c("Ind1","Ind1","Ind1","Ind1","Ind1","Ind1","Ind2",
                      "Ind2","Ind2","Ind3","Ind3","Ind3","Ind3","Ind4",
                      "Ind4","Ind4","Ind5","Ind5","Ind5","Ind5","Ind5",
                      "Ind5"),

           photo = c("55", "62", "63", "65", "70", "97", "100", "105",
                    "109", "72", "74", "76", "101", "140", "150", "170",
                    "168", "172", "182", "185", "189", "194"),


           data = c("jan/17", "mar/17", "mar/17", "apr/17",
                     "jun/17", "oct/17", "dec/17", "apr/18",
                     "may/18", "aug/17", "sep/17", "sep/17",
                     "dec/17", "aug/18", "nov/18", "feb/19",
                     "jan/19", "feb/19", "mar/19", "mar/19",
                     "mar/19", "jul/19"))
```

and I would like to generate a graph like this, with the names of individuals x date of the meeting. I wanted the size of the symbols according to the number of photos existing in that month, and the number of photos above the symbol ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drbef.png)).

Everything I find on the internet uses a data frame with two columns (starting x and final x)i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251160/plot-timeline-in-r-as-single-labeled-bar-and-with-dates-at-the-x-axis-labels) . Do I really need to separate into columns? And how to do with intermediary values??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can code your month/year data using `as.yearmon` from `zoo` package.

To count number of photos each month, would `group_by` and `summarise`.

To draw the line segments, would create a second data table to specify minimum and maximum dates.

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

my_table$ind <- factor(my_table$ind)
my_table$mo_yr <- as.yearmon(my_table$data, "%b/%y")

my_table_sum <- my_table %>%
  group_by(mo_yr, ind) %>%
  summarise(count = n())

my_table_range <- my_table_sum %>%
  group_by(ind) %>%
  summarise(min = min(mo_yr),
            max = max(mo_yr))

ggplot(data = my_table_sum, aes(x = mo_yr, y = ind)) +
  scale_x_yearmon() +
  geom_point(aes(size = count)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(count > 1, as.character(count), '')), vjust = -1) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 3), breaks = c(1,2,3)) +
  geom_segment(data = my_table_range, aes(x = min, xend = max, y = ind, yend = ind)) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(), legend.position="none")
```

[image: timeline plot]

**Edit**: For greater flexibility in x-axis ticks and labels, you might want to use `scale_x_date` instead of `scale_x_yearmon` (package `zoo` would not be needed).

`scale_x_date` will allow indication of breaks (every 3 months) and what you want in the label (right now month and 4 digit year, e.g., Mar 2019).

Instead of converting your `data` to a `yearmon` (month/year), we can just use `Date` (using 1st day of the month when converting).

Also added small margin around plot.

```
#library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

my_table$ind <- factor(my_table$ind)
#my_table$mo_yr <- as.yearmon(my_table$data, "%b/%y")
my_table$dates <- as.Date(paste0("1/", my_table$data), format = "%d/%b/%y")

my_table_sum <- my_table %>%
  group_by(dates, ind) %>%
  summarise(count = n())

my_table_range <- my_table_sum %>%
  group_by(ind) %>%
  summarise(min = min(dates),
            max = max(dates))

ggplot(data = my_table_sum, aes(x = dates, y = ind)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
  geom_point(aes(size = count)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(count > 1, as.character(count), '')), vjust = -1) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 3), breaks = c(1,2,3)) +
  geom_segment(data = my_table_range, aes(x = min, xend = max, y = ind, yend = ind)) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(), legend.position="none",
        plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm"))
```

[image: plot with ticks and labels every 3 months]

Comment: when I uses all my data, I see this 

Warning messages:
1: In self$trans$transform(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In self$trans$transform(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In self$trans$transform(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In self$trans$transform(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
5: Removed 66 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
6: Removed 27 rows containing missing values (geom_segment). 
7: Removed 66 rows containing missing values (geom_text)

Comment: it was a problem with a few months and years left, I solved by eliminating the lines that had some null information

Comment: Now only one month per year appears on the x-axis, with more data the number of items appearing on the x-axis has decreased. How to get values every 3 months on the x-axis

Comment: If you want flexibility on x-axis labels and ticks, we may want to use `scale_x_date` instead of `scale_x_yearmon`. I will update answer with an alternative in a moment.

Comment: I hope this helps. If this does not address your issue, please edit your question with an image of your plot that you wish to modify, and describe how you would like it to appear.